# Loop on objects in Array

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

I have Volley in my android application and when i call an api the data that should come from the server is like below:

```
{
  "services": [
    {
        "_id": "59f58f2c43f4aa7f7ec4ce4d",
        "name": "appName",
        "type": "app"
    },
    {
        "_id": "59f5b34e218e567f840bc592", 
        "name": "appName2", 
        "type": "app"
    }
  ]
}
```

And my code is like this:

```
new WebService(MainActivity.this, Request.Method.GET, "localhost:0000/api/v1/service",
            new TypeToken<JSONObject>() {
            }.getType(), new OnRequestStateChange<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject data) {
            Log.d("response length :", String.valueOf(data.length()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VolleyError error) {
            Log.d("response", "error");
        }
    })

    .start();
```

But the response length is 0 and the response is empty! How can i print these values?

any idea.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code of onResponse with below code. You are trying to call length on json object rather json array.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("services");
        Log.d("response length :", String.valueOf(jsonArray.length()));
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

```
"localhost:0000/api/v1/service"
```

This `URL` is wrong unless your `api` server runs on the same android device that also runs the app. Usually this is not the case. So replace the `localhost` part with the correct `IP` address of your api server and make sure the both server and android device are connecting to the same network.

Comment: I'm sorry, It just a string for here. i should write it like this: ip:port/api/v1/service .